# Saving a label's text using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save my score with `NSUserDefaults`. I want it to save the labels text, so when you open it back up the text is still there. I don't know where the code should go. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

struct Question {
    var Question : String!
    var Answers : [String]!
    var Answer : Int!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var highScoreLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var QLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var incorrectLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var theEnd: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!

    var scoreLbl = UILabel()
    var score = Int()
    var Questions = [Question]()
    var QNumber = Int()
    var AnswerNumber = Int()
    var wrongAnswers = Int()
    var highScore = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Questions = [Question(Question: "What is the Biggest Hit of Bing Crosby?" , Answers: ["Swinging on a Star", "Now is the Hour", "White Christmas", "Beautiful Dreamer"], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "What is Elvis Presely's Middle Name?", Answers: ["Aaron", "Micheal", "George", "Matthew"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "How Many Oscars did Titanic win?", Answers: ["5", "7", "10", "11"], Answer: 3),
        Question(Question: "From which country did Pitta Bread originate?", Answers: ["Spain", "France", "Greece", "Russia"], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "What is the largest living creature on Earth?", Answers: ["Whale", "Shark", "Sea Turtle", "Alligator"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "What does ATM stand for?", Answers: ["Automatic Treasure Machine", "Automatic Tax Machine", "Anti Tax Machine", "Automatic Teller Machine"], Answer: 3),
        Question(Question: "What's the world's second largest French speaking city?", Answers: ["Paris", "Montreal", "Versailles", "Québec"], Answer: 1),
        Question(Question: "What Country is the largest producer of Olive Oil?", Answers: ["Italy", "France", "Greece", "Spain"], Answer: 3),
        Question(Question: "How long is the Great Wall of China?", Answers: ["3200 miles", "4000 miles", "2000 kilometers", "4500 miles"], Answer: 1),
        Question(Question: "Who is on the 10 dollar bill?", Answers: ["George Washington", "Thomas Jefferson", "Alexander Hamilton", "John Adams" ], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "How many World Series did Yogi Berra win as a player?", Answers: ["11", "10", "5", "7" ], Answer: 1),
        Question(Question: "Which three countries hosted the Winter Olympics during the 1990's?", Answers: ["Norway, France, Russia", "US, Sweeden, Canada", "Japan, Canada, Germany", "Slovenia, France, South Korea" ], Answer: 0),]

        scoreLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(35, 45, 77, 45))
        scoreLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        scoreLbl.text = "-1"
        self.view.addSubview(scoreLbl)

        PickQuestions()

        saveHighScore()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func PickQuestions(){

        score++
        scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"

        if Questions.count > 0{
            QNumber = random() % Questions.count
            QLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

            AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

            for i in 0..<Buttons.count{
                Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }

            Questions.removeAtIndex(QNumber)
        }
        else{

            theEnd.text = "You Win!"
            theEnd.alpha = 1
            button1.enabled = false
            button2.enabled = false
            button3.enabled = false
            button4.enabled = false

            func reset(){
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You Win", message: "Click Restart To Play Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            reset()
        }

        saveHighScore()
        incorrectLabel.alpha = 0

    }

    func saveHighScore(){

        if score >= highScore {
            highScore = score
            highScoreLbl.text = "High Score: " + String(score)

        }
        else{}

    }
    @IBAction func Btn1(sender: AnyObject) {
        if AnswerNumber == 0{
            PickQuestions()
        }
        else{
            incorrectLabel.text = "You are incorrect!"
            incorrectLabel.alpha = 1
            score--
            scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
        }

    }
    @IBAction func Btn2(sender: AnyObject) {
        if AnswerNumber == 1{

            PickQuestions()
        }
        else{
            incorrectLabel.text = "You are Incorrect!"
            incorrectLabel.alpha = 1
            score--
            scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func Btn3(sender: AnyObject) {
        if AnswerNumber == 2{

            PickQuestions()
        }
        else{
            incorrectLabel.text = "You are Incorrect!"
            incorrectLabel.alpha = 1
            score--
            scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func Btn4(sender: AnyObject) {
        if AnswerNumber == 3{

            PickQuestions()
        }
        else{
            incorrectLabel.text = "You are Incorrect!"
            incorrectLabel.alpha = 1
            score--
            scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code at the top which looks like it has been left out of the code block marker.

Comment: Unrelated but it's a bad idea to hardcode all of your questions and answers in your code.

Comment: "I want it to save the labels text, so when you open it back up the text is still there." Are you saying you want to save the text as they type each letter? That way you could get it back if they were to force close the app or they went to another app and yours was closed due to memory pressure?

Comment: Its a score label. When I open it back up I want the labels text to be there still.

Comment: the `-viewDidLoad:` is definitely not the method you should trigger the `PickQuestions()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using **property observers**. Each time you set your score, your `didSet` block will check if your score is greater than the previous highscore, if it is it will run and store your high score into your NSUserDefaults.

> "Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current
>   value."

More information on property observers: [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var score: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"

            if score > highScore {
                // you could just as easily call a function here
                userDefaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "CurrentHighScore")
                //userDefaults.synchronize() // slow and unnecessary!
            } 
        }
    }
```

Then in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear retrieve your high-score value:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.scoreLbl.text = userDefaults.integerForKey("CurrentHighScore")

}
```

**Synchronize is not necessary iOS 8 and later:**

from http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

> Calling synchronize in an iOS 8 app will unnecessarily slow your
>   program, without giving a significant benefit.  I’ll let the document
>   speak for itself about the Performance Tradeoffs in NSUserDefaults:
>
> *"Reading from NSUserDefaults is extremely fast. It will cache values to*
>   *avoid reading from the disk, and takes about 0.5 microseconds to do*
>   *[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:] on a 2012 MacBook*
>   *Pro. It’s generally unnecessary (and even undesirable since it*
>   *prevents picking up new values) to cache the result of reading from*
>   *preferences.*
>
> *However, writing to NSUserDefaults is a bit slower. In general, expect*
>   *it to take roughly as long as using NSPropertyListSerialization to*
>   *convert your key and value to plist data, plus a few 10s of*
>   *microseconds. For this reason, as well as memory usage, it’s generally*
>   *best to store relatively small data in CFPreferences."*

Comment: and why you don't call  userDefaults.synchronize() after that?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has a specific method `integerForKey` to handle `Int` values, `valueForKey` is inappropriate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine everything that comes with changing the score into one method. That would be easier for you to manage and would make for a much cleaner code

```
func saveScore(newScore:Int){
    // Set the value of newScore to the class variable score
    score = newScore

    // Set the value of newScore to the scoreLbl
    scoreLbl.text = "\(newScore)"

    // Fetch User Defauls
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    // Save newScore value to the userDefaults
    userDefaults.setInteger(newScore, forKey: "score")

    // Synchronize userDefaults
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

This method will set the score, put it in the label and save the score to the user defaults at the same time. Just call this method whenever you want to update score instead of changing the value of score directly.